# Какой плагин для Notepad++ подсвечивает фоном новый текст?

Tags: notepad++

Доброго всем!

Решил использовать Notepad++ на полную и наставил для теста несколько десятков плагинов. В итоге сейчас один из них при изменении файла (добавлении любого текста) закрашивает фон изменённых строк в оранжевый цвет при ухода с них фокуса:

[image]

Если же файл с правками сохранить, то фон во всём файле становится зелёным:

[image]

Возможно, кто-то имеет представление, какой плагин может за это отвечать, и как можно хотя бы изменить цвет фона. )

Благодарю!

Answer (score 1):

ChangeMarker

А для замены цвета можно попробовать модифицировать конфиг-файл.

Answer (score 1):

плагин называется: Location Navigate